# меню для модальных окон

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, android-button

есть меню открытия окон

```html
<div class="meny">
    <button  onClick="document.getElementById('hide1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('hide2').style.display='none'; 
document.getElementById('hide3').style.display='none'; collapsElement('hide')">ОКНО1</button> 

<button  onClick="document.getElementById('hide').style.display='none';document.getElementById('hide2').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('hide3').style.display='none';collapsElement('hide1')">ОКНО2</button>

<button onClick="document.getElementById('hide').style.display='none';document.getElementById('hide1').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('hide3').style.display='none';collapsElement('hide2')">ОКНО3</button>

<button onClick="document.getElementById('hide').style.display='none';document.getElementById('hide1').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('hide2').style.display='none';collapsElement('hide3')">ОКНО4</button>

и так далее
  </div>
```

можно ли это как то сделать попроще

Answer (score 0):

Можно так написать. А вообще "проще" - слова размытое.

```
    <script>
            var arr = ['hide', 'hide1', 'hide2', 'hide3']
        function collapsElementId(id){
            for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                if (i!=id) document.getElementById(arr[i]).style.display='none';
            }
            collapsElement(arr[id]);
        }
    </script>

    <div class="meny">
        <button  onClick="collapsElementId(0);>ОКНО1</button> 
        <button  onClick="collapsElementId(1);>ОКНО2</button> 
        <button  onClick="collapsElementId(2);>ОКНО3</button> 
        <button  onClick="collapsElementId(3);>ОКНО4</button> 
и так далее
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  var bid = $(this).attr("id");
  $(".forhide").hide();
  var nid = bid.replace("btn", "");
  $("#wnd" + nid).show();
});
```

```css
.forhide {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<button id="btn1">ОКНО1</button> 
<button id="btn2">ОКНО2</button>
<button id="btn3">ОКНО3</button>
<button id="btn4">ОКНО4</button>
</div>
<div id="wnd1" class="forhide">1</div>
<div id="wnd2" class="forhide">2</div>
<div id="wnd3" class="forhide">3</div>
<div id="wnd4" class="forhide">4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ похож на ответ @DanIrkutskiy, но смысл в том, что в функцию передаем не индекс, а имя идентификатора. Добавим класс `'hide'` к элементам, которые будем скрывать и отображать, это для удобства, чтобы получить все элементы через [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). Если исходить из ваших условий и немного дополнить их, то так:

```js
function myFunc(id) {
  hideElements = document.getElementsByClassName('hide');

  for (var index = 0; index < hideElements.length; index++) {
    if (hideElements[index].id !== id) {
      hideElements[index].style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      collapsElement(id);
    }
  }
}

function collapsElement(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block'; // для наглядности
}
```

```css
.hide {}
```

```html
<div class="meny">
  <div id="hide" class="hide">0</div>
  <div id="hide1" class="hide">1</div>
  <div id="hide2" class="hide">2</div>
  <div id="hide3" class="hide">3</div>

  <button onClick="myFunc('hide');">Window 0</button>
  <button onClick="myFunc('hide1');">Window 1</button>
  <button onClick="myFunc('hide2');">Window 2</button>
  <button onClick="myFunc('hide3');">Window 3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Всем вот что получилось в итоге:

```js
function collapsElement(hide_id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(hide_id);
  if (el.style.display != "none") {
    el.style.display = 'none';

  } else {
    el.style.display = '';

  }
}

function hideElements(hide_id) {
  var hides = ['hide', 'hide1', 'hide2', 'hide3', 'hide4'];
  for (var i = 0; i < hides.length; i++) {
    if (hide_id !== hides[i]) {
      document.getElementById(hides[i]).style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  collapsElement(hide_id);
}
```

```css
.zet {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.div {
  background-color: #ff5a00;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 500;
  width: 300;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: #ff5a00;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 400;
  width: 400;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: #ff5a00;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300;
  width: 500;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.div3 {
  background-color: #ff5a00;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 200;
  width: 600;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.div4 {
  background-color: #ff5a00;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100;
  width: 700;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.meny {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  width: auto;
  border: 0px solid black;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #3333FF;
}

.close{
position:  absolute; top:0; right:0;  font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer; padding:6px 8px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="meny">
  <button onClick="hideElements('hide')">ОКНО1</button>
  <button onClick="hideElements('hide1')">ОКНО2</button>
  <button onClick="hideElements('hide2')">ОКНО3</button>
  <button onClick="hideElements('hide3')">ОКНО4</button>
  <button onClick="hideElements('hide4')">ОКНО5</button>
</div>


<div class="zet">
  <div id="hide" style="display:none" class="div">
    <span class="close" onclick="hideElements('hide')">X</span> Скрытый текст<br>Скрытый текст
  </div>
  <div id="hide1" style="display:none" class="div1">
    <span class="close" onclick="hideElements('hide1')">X</span> текст<br>
текст
  </div>
  <div id="hide2" style="display:none" class="div2">
    <span class="close" onclick="hideElements('hide2')">X</span> текст +<br>текст +
  </div>
  <div id="hide3" style="display:none" class="div3">
    <span class="close" onclick="hideElements('hide3')">X</span> текст + +<br>текст + +
  </div>
  <div id="hide4" style="display:none" class="div4">
  <span class="close" onclick="hideElements('hide4')">X</span> текст + + +<br>текст + + +
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! Повторяется (class="close") как сделать его уникальным для страницы